# Installing Amazon Inspector Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, inspector, data-security

I'm about to install and use **Amazon Inspector**. We have many **EC2** instances behind **ELB**. Plus some **EC2** instances are opened via **Auto-Scale**.

My question: Is the **Amazon Inspector** doing its work locally or globally, meaning is the monitoring being made on the instance that it is installed on or it can be configured to include all the instances of the infrastructure?

If Inspector should be applied on every **EC2** instance, can the **Auto-Scale** be configured to open the new instances with Inspector already installed on them and if yes, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer and the solution, You have to install **Amazon Inspector** on each **EC2** in order to inspect them all using **Amazon Inspector**.

About the **Auto-Scale**, I've applied Amazon Inspector on the main **EC2** servers and took an image from them (after inspecting all the **EC2s** and fix all the issues). Then I've configured the **Auto-Scale** to lunch to lunch from the new **AMIs** (The Inspected **AMIs**).

Comment: Is this still valid? I think it doesn't need to install. Just need to enable from the dashboard now it seems. I tried and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question on the Amazon forum but got no response.

In the end I used the following feature to customise the EC2 instances that my application gets deployed to:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Basically off the root of your .war file you need a folder named '.ebextensions' and in there a .config file containing some commands to install the Inspector client.

So my file 'inspector-agent.config' looks like this:

```
# Errors get logged to /var/log/cfn-init.log. See Also /var/log/eb-tools.log

commands:
# Download the agent installation script
  "01-agent-repository":
    command: sudo wget https://inspector-agent.amazonaws.com/linux/latest/install

# Run the installation script
  "02-run-installation-script":
    command: sudo bash install
```